# Error copying data from a csv file (with row number 2: found more columns than expected column count 41)

Tags: azure, csv, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have a csv file I am trying import and it keeps giving me error saying 'with row number 2:
found more columns than expected column count 41"

I check the data manually and none of them are going over 41 columns.

Strange thing is once I re save the file it seems to import fine. (another logic app drops file and I pick it form there).

if I resave the file and upload to same location then pipelines are picking it up fine. but issue with the file as is from logic app.

Please suggest for any ideas on what could be missing.

Strange thing is once I re save the file it seems to import fine. (another logic app drops file and I pick it form there).

if I resave the file and upload to same location then pipelines are picking it up fine. but issue with the file as is from logic app.

I have added double quote to big long text and other fields where there was comma etc..

sample row values ....
51495155,A,Closed,65676_T080,DI650I_SXXX,SXX,21B288,MISC2,AR,"This sample is contaminated by 1.0% water.  Check the seals, breathers and fill point for water entry points.  This sample is unsuitable for a particle count due to the amount of water in the oil.  The iron is slightly high.  Check any contamination capturing devices fitted for debris.  As this oil has been changed, suggest resample within 200 hrs to confirm the effectiveness of any adjustments or repairs.  For technical enquiries regarding this evaluation, please contact Maker Jok on (08) 9377 9521.",CO SRVS P L,GDI,XXXX,2022/12/06 00:00,2022/12/08 07:00,T08P-52342-2317,4765.0,620.0,,,,2022/12/10 00:12,2022/12/08 00:00,2022/12/08 00:00,,Y,N,,XXX,XXX S2 GX,320-ISO,,"ESCOTT, XXX",2022/12/06 00:00,,F,T,T080MJ,2022/12/09 18:30,F,

Answer (score 0):

I just realized there is an extra comma at the end which is assumed as the column.

Once its removed it is all good.